# Selenium, unable to get element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

i need to read the text from a element of a webpage via selenium. Here's the part of the page:

```
<div id="pDFEA208F010FEDCF6C6F0D5B5DDC97F3154" class="NPC_collapsable NPC_widget NPC_complete NPC_boxselect" data-boxtype="TOGGLE_BUTTONS" data-collapsed="true" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <header class="NPC_widget-header NPC_collapsing-title NPC_statusIcon">
    <h3 class="NPC_parameterText">Baugröße</h3>
    <span class="NPC_ellipsis NPC_unit"></span>
    <span class="NPC_ellipsis NPC_statusIcon" style="color:#0091dc!important"></span>
    <span class="NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue" style="font-weight: bold;">6</span>
    <span class="NPC_hint"></span>
  </header>
```

I can "adress" the section of the page via the `<h3>Baugröße</h3>`, what i need to get is the 6 from the last but one span.
I have:

```
    WebElement gruppe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//header/h3[text()='" + propertyName + "']"));
    System.out.println("Group: " + gruppe.getText() + " <");

    // Element in den sichtbaren Bereich(Focus) der Seite bewegen
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", gruppe);

    WebElement t1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//header/h3[text()='" + propertyName + "']/../span[@class='NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue']"));
    System.out.println("Try 1: >" + t1.getText() + "<");

    WebElement set = gruppe.findElement(
            By.xpath(".//following-sibling::*/span[@class='NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue']"));
    System.out.println("set: >" + set.getText() + "<");
```

Which gives me the group "Baugröße", but not the "6". I get:

```
Group: Baugröße <
Try 1: ><
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//following-sibling::*/span[@class='NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue']"} Command duration or timeout: 68 milliseconds
```

How can i get this span element?

Comment: Perhaps the `executeScript` call has unexpected side effects. Please try to remove this and/or move it before the `findElement` for `grpup`

Comment: i removed it, but nothing changes, i still don't get the "6".

Comment: You are sure that your html looks at test time as the above? Perhaps some JS adds or remove classes etc.? One test could be to change `span[@class='NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue']` to `span[text()='6']` or `span[3]` or `span[contains(@class, 'NPC_selectedParameterValue')]`

Comment: can u share the url if its public URL

Comment: **Problem solved,** my script was to quick! Shit, this took me hours to get it! Thank you verry much all of you who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

gruppe this is object of h3  and when you try to find element locator using gruppe  it will search element as a child of tag h3 and there is no child of H3 so it is giving exception element not found.

Now to get value 6 you should use driver object like below code:

```
 WebElement set = driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue')]"));
 System.out.println("set: >" + set.getText() + "<");
```

Comment: i added
`WebElement t2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//header/h3[text()='" + propertyName + "']/following-sibling::span[@class='NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue']"));`
`WebElement t3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//following-sibling::*/span[@class='NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue']"));`
Result: getText on t2 is empty, t3 raises:
`Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//following-sibling::*/span[@class='NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue']"}`

Comment: Just searching for `"//span[contains(@class, 'NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue')]"` wount work, because there are several of this on the page. I need exact the one next to the h3 with the text "Baugröße".

Answer (score 0):

In my view it is ok to start form `group` which is already the `hr` tag.
Also right is that the **span** you are looking  for is of the **h3** tag, but not a child in any level. Therefor the `.//following-sibling::*/` is wrong.
Try: `following-sibling::span[@class='NPC_ellipsis NPC_selectedParameterValue']`

But I do not see why **t1** does not has already the right element (span), so something else seems to be wrong.